Link server from on-premise Microsoft SQL Server to Azure SQL Server Managed Instance
I am trying to establish link server connection from Microsoft SQL Server which in on-premise to an Azure Microsoft SQL Server Managed Instance.
What steps are needed in creating the link server?

Could you please provide what you have tried?

lmgtfy

To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

You should enable  Public endpoint  in managed instance networking tab as shown below:

This option requires port 3342 to be open for inbound traffic. You will need to configure NSG rule for this port separately. So, create inbound rule for port 3342 by following this  MS document. After creating it use public endpoint you should below follow procedure to create linked server for Azure SQL managed instance :

On on-premises SQL server , navigate to the server object, right-click on Linked Server, and select New Linked Server, as shown below:



Provide the Azure SQL managed instance public endpoint , i.e.,  <sqlMIName>.public.2e06a1190d03.database.windows.net,3342, in the General section of the linked server, as shown below:



Go to the Security tab and select  Be made using the security context. Provide the username and password for the Azure SQL Managed Instance, as shown below:



Click OK. If all information is correct, the linked server will be tested and created successfully, as shown below:



@mahesh raju Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
